# Hibernate with struts2-jquery-grid. If i close session, grid not load data

Tags: jquery, hibernate, postgresql, struts2

I am developing a web application with struts2-jquery-grid and hibernate. It´s works when I don´t close the session, but if I close, the grid don´t load data of database.

The following code doesn´t work:

```
public List<Concurso> find(int o, int q){
    List<Concurso> concursoLst = null;
    sessao.beginTransaction();
    concursoLst = (ArrayList<Concurso>) sessao.createQuery("from Concurso order by nome").list();
    sessao.getTransaction().commit();
    sessao.close();
    return concursoLst;
```

But in other hand, if I comment sessao.close(), it works perfectly:

```
public List<Concurso> find(int o, int q){
    List<Concurso> concursoLst = null;
    sessao.beginTransaction();
    concursoLst = (ArrayList<Concurso>) sessao.createQuery("from Concurso order by nome").list();
    sessao.getTransaction().commit();
    //sessao.close();
    return concursoLst;
```

So, the execute() call this method:

```
    public String execute(){ 

    //code

    ConcursoDAO dao = new ConcursoDAO();
    gridModel = dao.find(from, to);

    //code
    }
```

Could someone help me????
Thanks!!

Comment: this is becuase how hibernate work, we usually call lazy loading,either create a separate DTO to store values received for the hibernate or use `openview session hibernate`

Comment: additionaly you can look at following plugin http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/

Comment: Umesh, i forgot to comment, i am newbie with hibernate =). So, could u send some link with a more specific solution? I didn´t get any error with the code. Thanks

Comment: what we are saying is that, the list you are fetching is lazy loaded so if you have not much data in your list, just fetch all data setting eager fetching mode and can close the session else use `Open session in view pattern` which will take care of closing your session

Comment: Hello Umesh. Using full hibernate plugin i get an error: ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Comment: i suggest you to read about handling session in web-application and if still have issue will upadate you with some working code

Comment: Using try/catch block I get gridModel null...

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your `Concurso`object has a list of lazy-loaded objects, and that they will not load because you've closed your session.

You need to supply us with more information, but for the time being, try setting

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

on the collections in `Concurso`, and read up on the Open session in view pattern, although some may call this an anti-pattern.

Comment: slipset, I tried it and doesn´t work.
Ok.
I have an entity "Concurso", "ConcursoDAO" where is the find() method, and an action "ListaConcurso", who build the list with the data accessed for DAO class.
Basiclly is it. The codes are extensive, so i thinking in not copy here. But if u think it´s better, i can post. Thanks

Comment: Maybe post a stack-trace if you have one?